# Does it matter which portal a field is closed from

Tags: ingress

If you have a field made from portals A, B and C, does it make any difference to the MU count which portal is the "closing" one?

For example, if you have a portal in a city and a portal in the countryside will there be a bigger MU gain by closing the field from the city portal?

Answer (score 2):

No, generally you'll link them in whatever path is more convenient/allows you to get them linked up quickly before the opposing faction comes and wrecks it. Keep in mind that while the MU is nice, layering will give you better protection for your inner fields.

Comment: Two conflicting answers - I'll be in a position to experiment with large enough fields shortly. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Makes no difference where the last link is from or to.  MU is calculated from the area contained inside the field.  In the city, the higher population produces more MU than the rural areas.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Is suppossed that when you close a field (lets suppose that cover the same Area.. lets say for example 4km2) it will give you more or less Mu depending where you close.

Is not the same close it in a big city, than in the countryside....because is supposed that there  are less people to "control".

SO, the same field, in New York, will give you for example 4000 Mus, but if you do in the country side, will give you for example 2000.

Comment: Two conflicting answers - I'll be in a position to experiment with large enough fields shortly. Thanks for the response.

Comment: This answers a different question -- the original deals with three specific portals in a specific place; this compares fields of equal area in different places.